# Squaring Numbers in java using Math.pow getting error of precision

Tags: java, math, pow, exponentiation

I have do to a question to write a method to input an array of type LONG that stores the values of all the powers of 2 from 0 to 63 (i.e. 2<sup>0</sup> to 2<sup>63</sup>)

Output the contects of the array screen.
Hint: Math.pow(x,y) is ued to put number x to exponent y

so far I have something like

I keep getting error or Math.pow(size,2); required long, found double. 
I tried Math.pow(i,2); I get same error./ possible loss of precision ,, any help :) thanks

```
class ws3q2
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

        int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;

        long size = ARRAY_SIZE;

        long[] array = new long[ARRAY_SIZE];

        for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
        {
        array[i] = Math.pow(size,2);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the *exact* error message so that we can help you.

Comment: For squaring it's much easier to just write `size * size`.

Comment: hmm I think i might of had that code wrong, I have another code another way of trying it since if you read the question its suppose to square it but with out me putting the int array_size = 5 ;

hmm im just new here i cant answer my own question so i cant post my different code i tried./

Comment: @user3392994: Instead of answering your question, you can edit it. Which is appropriate unless you actually have an answer yourself. For example, you could edit the question to clarify whether you want to ask about squaring of about powers of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Better shift

For 2<sup>*x*</sup> where *x* ∈ ℕ, you are better off writing this as a bit shift

```
1L << x
```

instead of a floating point exponentiation

```
pow(2, x)
```

both in terms of precision and in terms of performance. In fact, `1L << x` is so easy to compute that I'd prefer writing that instead of `array[x]`, so you might perhaps avoid the array altogether.

## More errors?

`pow(x, 2)` as you write in your code would be *x*<sup>2</sup> which you could compute more easily as `x*x`. So which one is it to be, powers of two or squares?

Furthermore, you write `pow(size,2)` which uses `size` and does not depend on `i`. So all values of your array would be equal. I guess that is not what you meant.

## Where your error comes from

The reason of the error message is the fact that the result of `Math.pow` is double, and implicit conversion from `double` to `long` is forbidden in Java. You'd have to write an explicit cast, i.e. `(long)pow(2, x)`. But that does round towards zero, so a slight numeric error might cause a wrong result. The only exactness guarantee you have for `Math.pow` is this:

> The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result.

You could add `0.5` before doing the conversion, or use `Math.round` instead of the cast, but as you see, you have to know *a lot* about the internal workings of floating point math to get this correct. Better to stick to integer math and avoid `double` and `Math.pow` altogether.

Comment: hmm sorry still very new to java, just started college first year.. can you explain a bit more to where to place all that in my code thanks would really help alot

Comment: @user3392994: No, sorry, I won't write your code for you. Try working this out on your own, with a bit of trial and error perhaps, and a bit of searching the web, and even though it will take a bit longer, you will learn stuff in the process. Stuff about Java, but also stuff about how to find information.

Comment: Thanks the part about error comes from, helped me alot. I get it a bit more now and I think i have it fixed, to square root 0 to 63 since Math.pow is double. and converting to long, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is that `Math.pow` returns a `double`, where you want a `long`.

But the whole point of your array is not clear. Whenever you write:

```
array[i]
```

you can as well write:

```
1L << i
```

and get the same result.

Plus, you will even save the array bounds check.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `long[] array = new long[ARRAY_SIZE];`, use `double[] array = new double[ARRAY_SIZE];` so that your program looks like:

```
class ws3q2
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
        long size = ARRAY_SIZE;
        double[] array = new double[ARRAY_SIZE];
        for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
        {
            array[i] = Math.pow(size,2);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
If you want `long`, then convert it, `array[i]=(long)Math.pow(size,2);`
OR
Covert it to long afterwards by storing it in a temp. array.

Comment: You have the arguments to pow in wrong order. And if you would read the other answers, you'd notice that invoking Math.pow to gain an integral power of 2 is just overkill, like using a nuclear reactor to frie eggs.

Comment: You mean to fry an egg? Don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First of all Math.pow() returns a double. Your array is of type long. Secondly, you have the parameters for your pow in the wrong order, the first parameter is the base, the second the exponent. Lastly, you are using the wrong variable for your exponent (size is always the same). Lastly be aware that 2^63 is too large to be accurately represented by a double. If you want to use longs, you should use the (Logical) Shift Left operator instead, as others have mentioned.

Here, I fixed it for you:

```
class ws3q2
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
        long size = ARRAY_SIZE;
        double[] array = new double[ARRAY_SIZE];
        for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
        {
            array[i] = Math.pow(2, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks helps abit more./ Just the issue I have its kind of not supposed to have array_size = 5 ; its not supposed for me to set what its supposed to square. since it askes to store powers of 2. from 0 to 63
just with that code that you have fixed for me./ the array is double I need it long so it can go higher square. not just up to 24^2

Comment: Increase ARRAY_SIZE to 63.

Comment: done it now:) thanks guys helped alot. see I didn't know that math.pow is a double and you have to convert, Found out how to do it with all ye guys help thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cause for the actual error message, **loss** of precision, is that you want, in the argument of pow, to stuff a long integer of 64bit into a double that only can represent integers of 53bit exactly. You get the same message if you want to assign a double value to a float.

Which could be avoided by using type int for the input. For the square to fit into an 64bit signed integer, the argument can not be (much) longer than signed 32bit, and for a power of 2, the exponent has to be smaller than 63.

Or use, for `cosa < (1<<26)`,

```
array[i] = (long)Math.pow((double)cosa,2);
```